# How to reorder HTML dropdown list using PHP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I downloaded a Wordpress plugin (Ultimate Memeber- User Tags Extension) that allows me to apply tags and then filter those tags in a dropdown menu, but won't let me reorder the dropdown menu. Here's the HTML of the dropdown:

```
<select class="um-s1" id="days_tag" name="days_tag" data-placeholder="Days Open">
    <option></option>       
    <option value="19" data-value_label="Fridays">Fridays</option>                              
    <option value="15" data-value_label="Mondays">Mondays</option>
    <option value="20" data-value_label="Saturdays">Saturdays</option>                      
    <option value="21" data-value_label="Sundays">Sundays</option>              
    <option value="18" data-value_label="Thursdays">Thursdays</option>                  
    <option value="16" data-value_label="Tuesdays">Tuesdays</option>
    <option value="17" data-value_label="Wednesdays">Wednesdays</option>                                
</select>
```

Here's the PHP that creates the array curently:

```
function um_multiselect_options_user_tags( $options, $data ) {

    $tags = UM()->User_Tags()->get_localized_terms( array(
        'child_of'  => $data['tag_source'],
    ) );

    if ( ! $tags ) {
        return array( '' );
    }

    $options = array();
    foreach ( $tags as $term ) {
        $id = $term->term_id;
        $options[ $id ] = $term->name;
    }
    return $options;
}
add_filter( 'um_multiselect_options_user_tags', 'um_multiselect_options_user_tags', 100, 2 );
```

I downloaded another plugin to try to reorder the selections into day order and it added the values, but didn't actually reorder them. How can I use PHP to sort the options by value? I'm brand new to PHP and pretty lost on this. I'm also open to non-PHP solutions as well!

Comment: which plugin are you using? I don't see any php code either. Could you post what you tried yet?

Comment: @Mainz007 I updated my post to inlude the plugin name and php

Comment: sorry but I can't help you with the issue